# Starting thread from for loop blocks UI

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, block

I am compressing video and in the future I'd like to compress multiple frames at once. I have a thread and I call it to do work on each of the frames - that's why I have for loop in my UI class. The problem is that UI is blocked. Why? Is this becuase I am calling the thread from for loop?

Code causing UI block (Dialog.cpp):

```
for(int i=0; i<nFrames; i++)
{
    //grab next frame from video source

    myThread.setFrame(newFrame);
    myThread.start();
    myThread.wait();
    result.append(myThread.GetResult());
}
```

Comment: What's the point in starting a separate thread and immediately waiting for it?

Comment: I used wait() because without it the thread will be restarted immediately by for loop, producing no result. Isn't that correct?

Comment: The problem is if you immediately block waiting for the thread to finish there is no point in the thread at all. Your single threaded UI blocks and yields to a second thread and continues to yield until the task is complete in the second thread. You could have just done the work the main thread in that case. You can not create a thread in a loop like this. You may want to use signals and slots, QtConcurrent or a thread pool to accomplish this however I do not have the time to explain either solution.

Comment: No need for explaining, I will read about it myself. Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `wait`, why would you expect that `wait` won't block ui?

From Qt docs:

> Blocks the thread until either of these conditions is met:
>
> The thread associated with this QThread object has finished execution
>   (i.e. when it returns from run()). This function will return true if
>   the thread has finished. It also returns true if the thread has not
>   been started yet. time milliseconds has elapsed. If time is ULONG_MAX
>   (the default), then the wait will never timeout (the thread must
>   return from run()). This function will return false if the wait timed
>   out.

Comment: But if I don't use wait(), then the for-loop wil restart the thread before it does anything? Should I use a new thread for each of my frames?

Comment: @PrimožKralj if you want to do more than 1 thing at once, you need more than 1 thread.  Note that an uncontrolled number of threads is a bad idea, and will slow you down more than doing it in a single thread.  You probably need something like a task pool, and a producer-consumer queue, and the like.

Answer (score 2):

[From doc:](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qthread.html#wait)

> bool QThread::wait ( unsigned long time = ULONG_MAX )
>
> Blocks the thread until either of these conditions is met:
>
> The thread associated with **this QThread object** has finished execution (i.e. when it returns from run()).
>
> ...
>
> This provides similar functionality to the POSIX **pthread_join**()
>   function.

You shouldn't use `wait` here.